# Converting C code to mips gives error

Tags: mips

This is the C code that i have been converted so far. it gives me some error that i have been included in the following code. i don't understand which part is wrong in this c to mips conversion?

```
 char ch[10];
 int i;
 for (i = 0; i != 10; i++)
 ch[i] = ch[i] – 32


.data

.text
li  $v0 4
syscall

#$s1 = i, $s0  base address of ch

addi $s1, $0, 0                #i =0
addi $t0, $0, 10               #t0 = 10
loop:   beq  $t0, $s1, end       
add  $t1, $s1, $s0
lw   $t2, 0($t1)
addi $t2, $t2, -32
sw   $t2, 0($t1)
addi $s1, $s1, 1
j   loop
end:
```

My output:

```
Runtime exception at 0x00400018: address out of range 0x00000000
```

Comment: It's been a while since MIPS for me, but it looks like an empty register. More importantly, you should be commenting line by line when you code in MIPS otherwise debugging will be a nightmare.

Comment: You're not initializing `$s0`. Also, it's unclear what that `syscall` is supposed to do, since system call 4 expects a string address in `$a0`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the C code you are converting a `char` type array and in MIPS you should use `lb` instead of `lw`.

In order to print out you need a `main:` label and also you should declare an array like `.byte` or `.space`

You should use`syscall 11` to print a character or `syscall 4` to print 
string.

I have added some of these mentioned above to your code hope it helps.

```
    .data
     #ch: .byte 'a','b','c','d','e'
     ch: .space 10
    .text
     main:


            li $v0, 8      #read character 
            li $a1, 10     #load the space
            la $a0, ch     
            syscall

            li $v0,11      #print character
            syscall

            li $v0,10      # exit program
            syscall

            addi $s1, $0, 0     #i = 0
            addi $t0, $0, 10    # $t0 = 10
    loop:   beq  $t0, $s1, end  
            add  $t1, $s1, $s0  
            lb   $t2, ch($t1)   
            addi $t2, $t2, -32
            sb   $t2, ch($t1)
            addi $s1, $s1, 1
            j   loop
    end:
```